# Convert vectors into array list

Tags: c++

How can I convert my `vector`s to `proc` array?

I have a couple of functions later that take only 1 argument, and I would like to change my code to take values from the text file. I was thinking about using a dynamic array, because different files will have different lengths, but I don't know how to create it.

```cpp
vector<int> vec1, vec2, vec3;
int element1, element2, element3;
char comma;
ifstream infile("jobs.txt");
if (!infile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
}
else {
    while (infile >> element1 >> comma >> element2 >> comma >> element3)
    {
        vec1.push_back(element1);
        vec2.push_back(element2);
        vec3.push_back(element3);
    }
}
    
arrSize = vec1.size();
count1 = arrSize;
cout << arrSize << endl;
        
Process proc[] = { { 1, 18, 3 }, { 2, 5, 1 },
                   { 3, 14, 5 }, { 4, 1, 1 },{ 5, 17, 0 }, { 6, 2, 6 } ,{ 7, 6, 2 }, { 8, 15, 7 } ,{ 9, 20, 0 }, { 10, 6, 8 },
                   { 11, 18, 0 }, { 12, 2, 1 }, { 13, 3, 5 }, { 14, 2, 3 }, { 15, 2, 0 }, { 16, 7, 2 }, { 17, 20, 4 }, { 18, 4, 4 },
                   { 19, 17, 9 }, { 20, 1, 0 }    };
int n = sizeof(proc) / sizeof(proc[0]);
      
findavgTime(proc, n);

return 0;
```

This is my input file that I want to use:

```
1,18,3
2,5,1
3,14,5
4,1,1
5,17,0
6,2,6
7,6,2
8,15,7
9,20,0
10,6,8
11,18,0
12,2,1
13,3,5
14,2,3
15,2,0
16,7,3
17,20,4
18,4,4
19,17,9
20,1,0
```

Comment: C++ does not work this way. All C++ arrays have a fixed size, determined at compile time. An array with varying length is called "vector".

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik More specifically, *C-style* arrays, not to be confused with `std::vector`.

Comment: What's the function signature for `findavgTime(proc, n)`? Is that something you can alter? If you structure your vector just *so* you might be able to use `data()` to return a compatible memory layout. I'd suggest a single `std::vector` which you add triplets of values to.

Comment: This is CPU burst program Shortest Job first an findavgTimes calculates the average time that CPU spent.

Comment: Don't care what it does. Do care *how* you're supposed to call it.

Comment: void findavgTime(Process proc[], int n)
{
    int wt[n], tat[n], total_wt = 0,
                    total_tat = 0;
  
    
    findWaitingTime(proc, n, wt);
  
   findTurnAroundTime(proc, n, wt, tat);}

Comment: If you can alter the function, just make it take your `vector` structure(s). Also try and edit your question to include code. It's just a wreck in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single `std::vector` of `Process` elements, have your reading loop `push_back()` complete `Process` objects into the vector, and then pass the vector's `data()` pointer to `findavgTime()`, eg:

```cpp
vector<Process> procs;
int element1, element2, element3;
char comma;

ifstream infile("jobs.txt");
if (!infile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
}
else {
    while (infile >> element1 >> comma >> element2 >> comma >> element3)
    {
        Process proc{element1, element2, element3};
        procs.push_back(proc);
    }
    infile.close();
}
    
cout << procs.size() << endl;

findavgTime(procs.data(), static_cast<int>(procs.size()));

return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, you are awesome!